# How to pass parameter through link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Controller

```
class FeedEntriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = FeedEntry.search(params[:search])
    @feed_entries = @search.page(params[:page])
    @app_keys = AppKey.all
  end
end
```

My feed_entries/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Stared", {:controller => "feed_entries", :action => "index", :search => ['is_star = ?', true] }%>
```

feed_entries table contain `is_star:boolean` attribute. So, I just want to pass the parameter is_star == true into the params[:search].

But the above code is not working. Please some one help me.

Comment: when do you check if `is_star` is `true/false?` . And `params[:search]`, if its a string you cant pass in other object type. So you gonna have to run a query to check if `is_start` is true or false before or after depending on your workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<%= link_to "Stared", {:controller => "feed_entries", :action => "index", :is_star => true } %?
```

And then you should be able to access in the controller using `params[:is_star]`

Comment: also not working, getting error like below:undefined method `stringify_keys!' for "true":String

Comment: Which line in the controller gives you the error? And which version of Ruby/Rails are you using?

Comment: i am getting error in browser like below . NoMethodError in FeedEntriesController#index

undefined method `stringify_keys!' for "true":String

Rails.root: /home/arunkumark/rails_projects/intertask/rss_feeds
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/feed_entries_controller.rb:3:in `index'

Request

Parameters:

{"is_star"=>"true"}

Comment: And i am using rails-'3.2.9' version

Comment: params[:search] doesn't exist anymore. Using the code I posted above it should be something like `@search = FeedEntry.search(is_star: params[:search])`